# how to retrive access tokens from oauth for withings in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, withings

I an new in dotnet and i want to retrive access tokens from oauth i have api key and secret but when i creat final url to be hit to retrive tokens it response (The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.)
My final url is 
https://oauth.withings.com/account/request_token?oauth_callback=https://localhost:15626/Default.aspx&oauth_consumer_key=18cb37fb4fb6fbf75288c2e70d373cdefe535689fd1de80756feec2622e&oauth_nonce=2794396&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_signature=sX4nv2hedzTU9Qih8RFw%3d&oauth_timestamp=1392386140&oauth_version=1.0

please help me to successfuly retriving oauth token and oauth secret. thank you.

Comment: Are you properly encoding your parameters?  have you tried using POSTman plugin from Chrome, just to check things easily?

Comment: I'm having the same situation , any clues ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.

Make sure, that all your parameters are spelled correctly and that you URL-Encode the oauth_callback parameter:

```
string requestUri = baseRequestTokenUri + "?oauth_callback=" + Uri.EscapeUriString(oAuthCallback);
```

Also make sure, that you use the correct signing key:

for `../request_token?` this should be: `{ConsumerSecret}`+"&"+`{RequestTokenSecret}`

HTH
Dominik